# sql Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and have run into a problem.  I have searched and read many posts about this error but I can't seem to connect any of the answers to my problem.  As far as I can see I'm not doing the same thing, trying to return 2 columns in my `SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO `countries` (
    `alpha2_id`, `alpha3_id`, `numeric_id`, `common_name`,
    `formal_name`, `capital`, `type_id`, `subtype_id`,
    `un_admission_date`, `eu_accession_date`, `anthem`, `motto`,
    `flag_name`, `seal_name`, `coa_name`
)
VALUES (
    'AF', 'AFG', '004', 'Afghanistan', 'Islamic State of Afghanistan', 'Kabul',
    (
        SELECT id_no FROM `country_types`
        WHERE `type_id`='T' AND `description`='Independent State'
    ),
    (
        SELECT id_no FROM `country_types`
        WHERE `type_id`='S' AND `description`=''
    ),
    '1946/11/19', null, 'Afghan National Anthem', '', 'af.png', '', 'af_coa.png'
);
```

This test query works fine but when I try to add a 2nd line I get the SQL error 1241.

```
INSERT INTO `countries` (
    `alpha2_id`, `alpha3_id`, `numeric_id`, `common_name`,
    `formal_name`, `capital`, `type_id`, `subtype_id`,
    `un_admission_date`, `eu_accession_date`, `anthem`, `motto`,
    `flag_name`, `seal_name`, `coa_name`
)
VALUES (
    (
        'AF', 'AFG', '004', 'Afghanistan', 'Islamic State of Afghanistan', 'Kabul',
        (
            SELECT id_no FROM `country_types`
            WHERE `type_id`='T' AND `description`='Independent State'
        ),
        (
            SELECT id_no FROM `country_types`
            WHERE `type_id`='S' AND `description`=''
        ),
        '1946/11/19', null, 'Afghan National Anthem', '', 'af.png', '', 'af_coa.png'
    ),
    (
        'AL', 'ALB', '008', 'Albania', 'Republic of Albania', 'Tirana',
        (
            SELECT id_no FROM `country_types`
            WHERE `type_id`='T' AND `description`='Independent State'
        ),
        (
            SELECT id_no FROM `country_types`
            WHERE `type_id`='S' AND `description`=''
        ),
        '1955/12/14', null, 'Himni i Flamurit (United around the flag)', 'Ti, Shqipëri, më jep nder, më jep emrin Shqipëtar (You, Albania, give me honor, give me the name Albanian)', 'al.png', '', 'al_coa.png'
    )
);
```

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

**EDIT:** I have a csv file with 198 countries that I have to insert into a mysql table.  I can't insert the data as a csv because I need to convert 2 text fields (`type_id` and `subtype_id`) into `int` fields.  Since I'm new to SQL, I searched this website and found the syntax to use.  The single import works fine so I again searched this website to get the syntax for multiple inserts.  This is the format I found:

```
INSERT INTO `countries` (col-names)
VALUES (
    (data fields to insert),
    (data fields to insert)
);
```

The above sample is 5 lines, might not show up this way, I'm still learning how to format my posts.  If I can get 2 lines of values to work then I can add the other 196 lines.

I have placed a sample txt file [here](http://www.cef-inc.com/testing/Countries_Import.sql). Your browser might wrap so you might want to look at the source.

Comment: Isn't the syntax "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (a1, b1), (a2, b2)"?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You have double parenthesis in your second set of values, `VALUES (('AF'`

Comment: check all queries, I think they are returning multiple rows

Comment: Check the parameters

Comment: As far as I can tell my format matches examples I found posted here.  The double parenthesis are required when importing more than 1 line.  At least that's what the SO post I read claims.  Also, there are no duplicates in the 'country_types' table, I have checked.  I think this means my queries are only returning 1 row.

Comment: I have tested both code segments posted below and I still get the same error: 1241.  Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO countries
(
    alpha2_id,
    alpha3_id,
    numeric_id,
    common_name,
    formal_name,
    capital,
    type_id,
    subtype_id,
    un_admission_date,
    eu_accession_date,
    anthem,
    motto,
    flag_name,
    seal_name,
    coa_name
)
VALUES (
    (
        'AF',
        'AFG',
        '004',
        'Afghanistan',
        'Islamic State of Afghanistan',
        'Kabul',
        (
            SELECT id_no
            FROM   country_types
            WHERE  type_id='T'
            AND    description='Independent State'),
        (
            SELECT id_no
            FROM   country_types
            WHERE  type_id='S'
            AND    description=''),
        '1946/11/19',
        NULL,
        'Afghan National Anthem',
        '',
        'af.png',
        '',
        'af_coa.png'
    )
    ,
    (
        'AL', 'ALB', '008', 'Albania', 'Republic of Albania', 'Tirana',
        (
            SELECT id_no
            FROM   country_types
            WHERE  type_id='T'
            AND    description='Independent State'),
        (
            SELECT id_no
            FROM   country_types
            WHERE  type_id='S'
            AND    description=''),
        '1955/12/14',
        NULL,
        'Himni i Flamurit (United around the flag)',
        'Ti, Shqipëri, më jep nder, më jep emrin Shqipëtar (You, Albania, give me honor, give me the name Albanian)',
        'al.png',
        '',
        'al_coa.png'
    )
)
";
```

Comment: Your post shows "; at the end but I don't see any opening ".  Was this a mistake?  My format is basically the same as yours. Line 1 is the INSERT INTO table (columns). Line 2 is VALUES (. Line 3 and 4 is the data and Line 5 is the closing );.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into MySQL Workbench and it complained about the next to the end " character.  I removed it and ran the code, I still get the exact same error message: 1241

Answer (score 0):

Your Query Should look like this

```
INSERT INTO countries
(
alpha2_id, alpha3_id, numeric_id, 
common_name,formal_name, capital, 
type_id, subtype_id, un_admission_date, 
eu_accession_date, anthem, motto, 
flag_name, seal_name, coa_name
 )

 Select 'AF', 'AFG', '004', 
'Afghanistan', 'Islamic State of Afghanistan', 'Kabul',
(SELECT id_no FROM `country_types` WHERE `type_id`='T' AND `description`='Independent State')as TypeId,
(SELECT id_no FROM `country_types` WHERE `type_id`='S' AND `description`='')as subtype_id,
'1946/11/19' as un_admission_date, null,
'Afghan National Anthem', '', 'af.png','', 'af_coa.png'
 /*  In Column  eu_accession_date You are Passing Null Please check whether  
 you column can contain null or not*/
```

Comment: Your post shows 'Select 'AF', etc...' but should it be VALUES instead?  Anyway, I am able to import 1 line okay.  But, I have another 197 lines to import so I was trying to use multiple lines.  And yes, the date field does accept null if it is blank (in fact I'm forced to use null because I can't get a data type to accept a default of blank '').

Comment: I entered your syntax into MySQL Workbench but it complained.  I had to enclose the VALUES in (...) and I also had to remove all the AS portions. (I get a red X only any line that has an error)